# Not getting the required output using Wordnet Synset's definition method

Tags: python, output, nltk, owl, wordnet

```
 from nltk.corpus import wordnet 
 syn=wordnet.synsets('cookbook')[0]
 print syn.definition
```

Expected Output:

```
'a book of recipes and cooking directions'
```

Actual Output:

```
bound method Synset.definition of Synset('cookbook.n.01')
```

I am unable to pinpoint the error in my code which is causing the difference between the actual output and the expected output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> wn.synsets('dog')[0]
Synset('dog.n.01')
>>> wn.synsets('dog')[0].definition
<bound method Synset.definition of Synset('dog.n.01')>
>>> wn.synsets('dog')[0].definition()
u'a member of the genus Canis (probably descended from the common wolf) that has been domesticated by man since prehistoric times; occurs in many breeds'
```

It's because `Synset` object properties has been changed to `Synset` functions, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/commit/ba8ab7e23ea2b8d61029484098fd62d5986acd9c

Comment: Thanks :). I was going crazy browsing for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot about the `()` after `.definition` bro.

try this line below, it will work.

`print(wn.synsets('dog')[0].definition())`