# NetworkX and Wordnet

Tags: nltk, networkx

Managed to create a hypernym graph but keep on getting bound method Synset.name of Synset('dog.n') instead of dog.n in the graph. Where is the mistake?

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def closure_graph(synset, fn):
    seen = set()
    graph = nx.DiGraph()

    def recurse(s):
        if not s in seen:
            seen.add(s)
            graph.add_node(s.name)
            for s1 in fn(s):
                graph.add_node(s1.name)
                graph.add_edge(s.name, s1.name)
                recurse(s1)

    recurse(synset)
    return graph


dog = wn.synsets('dog')[0]
G = closure_graph(dog,
                      lambda s: s.hypernyms())
index = nx.betweenness_centrality(G)
plt.rc('figure', figsize=(12, 7))
node_size = [index[n]*1000 for n in G]
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, node_size=node_size, edge_color='r', alpha=.3, linewidths=0)
plt.show()
```

**Edit 1:**

Managed to create a hypernym graph but keep on getting bound method Synset.name of Synset('dog.n') instead of dog.n in the graph. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Can you provide a complete example [MCVE] and can you tell us what you expect to happen in this code and what does happen?

Comment: Please see Edit 1.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're describing for the output.  But it looks like the function that creates the graph is doing something different in creating the nodes than you expect.  I suspect that has something to do with the fact that you've defined `dog` to be `wn.synsets('dog')[0]`, while the link you provide has `dog = wn.synset('dog.n.01')`.

Comment: The issue is as explained in this link, thats why I added [0] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27795623/not-getting-the-required-output-using-wordnet-synsets-definition-method

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know what the error is (I can get the graph you're after on my machine).  I would have found it a lot quicker if you had provided the full code necessary to reproduce your error.  Before I say for sure what it is, I'd like to make sure that `wn`, `nx`, and `closure_graph` are defined the way I think they are.  Can you provide a [MCVE]?  It should be something I can just copy and paste and have it run.

Comment: I amended the question with M,C and V example. It runs to provide a messy graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what is printing out is that `networkx` has created a bunch of nodes, each node being a function.  So we need to look at the command that is adding nodes.  This occurs in `closure_graph`.

In the definition of `closure_graph`, we see that `s.name` is added as a node.  This is a function (it probably used to actually be the name before `nltk` was updated).  Instead you want to add `s.name()` which is now a function that returns the name.  There are 4 places where this occurs.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def closure_graph(synset, fn):
    seen = set()
    graph = nx.DiGraph()

    def recurse(s):
        if not s in seen:
            seen.add(s)
            graph.add_node(s.name())
            for s1 in fn(s):
                graph.add_node(s1.name())
                graph.add_edge(s.name(), s1.name())
                recurse(s1)

    recurse(synset)
    return graph


dog = wn.synsets('dog')[0]
G = closure_graph(dog,
                      lambda s: s.hypernyms())
index = nx.betweenness_centrality(G)
plt.rc('figure', figsize=(12, 7))
node_size = [index[n]*1000 for n in G]
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, node_size=node_size, edge_color='r', alpha=.3, linewidths=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]